# Truncating TEMP table before insert leads to big amount of logical reads on TEMP TABLE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, temporary-tables, truncate

Setup:
We have a complex set of queries, that runs quite often (about 3000 times per hour) for different users. 
At the start of the process, .NET application creates a set of temp tables
during the process, .NET application calls a set of SQL queries, they look like this:

```
truncate #QuerySpecificTable

insert into #QuerySpecificTable
select PrimaryKey
  from Production.QuerySpecificTable
  join ...
 where ...
```

Issue i came across while performance tuning one specific query. ~139000 records get inserted into the temp table. This causes ~300k logical reads on the #QuerySpecificTable.

When i remove the truncate, it drops to ~300 reads on #QuerySpecificTable.
CPU statistics show drop in CPU time (~900->300ms so not sure about precision and reliability.)

The issue is, when trying to do this in SSMS, i cannot 100% reproduce the behaviour and make sure and demonstrate removing the truncate (even through it wouldnt be a problem) is a good thing to do. The biggest issue is **NOT KNOWING** why and what is happening here

**WITH TRUNCATE (NOT ALWAYS, thats the weird part)**

```
truncate table #test
insert into #test select top 150000 PrimKey from dbo.test

Table '#test_______________________________________________________________________ ________________________________________000000000141'. Scan count 0, logical reads 319955, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 217, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Test'. Scan count 1, logical reads 246, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(150000 rows affected)
```

**DROP/CREATE**

```
drop table if exists #test
create table #test (PrimKey integer primary key) 
truncate table #test
insert into #test select top 150000 PrimKey from dbo.test

Table 'Test'. Scan count 1, logical reads 246, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 232, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(150000 rows affected)
```

Comment: What is point in truncating the temp table, would it not be possible to simply drop and recreate it.

Comment: @Shanky yes, the truncate is completely useless and can be removed. Its a old, deprecated line from the dark ages of the company. Nevermind. The question here is not if truncate can or cannot be dropped. The question is: Why the behavior, whats the issue? I don't like fixing something if i dont understand the issue

Comment: Are you stating that inserting 139,000 rows only results in 300 reads? That seems extremely unlikely.

Comment: Yes. create table #test (PrimKey integer primary key)

insert into #test
select top 150000 PKColumn from Production.BigTable

with set statistics io on shows no logical reads on tmp table. The same try with non-temp table shows reads

Comment: @VladislavZalesak What you are telling above is wrong you sure are missing something. You are saying that for temp tables there would be no logical reads and for physical table there would be for same set of query. Frankly that does not makes sense

Comment: Just tried it. This is Statistics io output:
Table 'Test'. Scan count 1, logical reads 246, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(150000 rows affected)

Comment: I believe we are not on same page, I also tried with small code and I did get logical reads in both the cases

Comment: For the community to be able to assist you, we would require further information. It would help if you could provide the `#temp` table definition. I think your code is doing something different that what happens when you execute it in SSMS. That is possibly the reason you are observing different behaviour. Next: If you turn on client stats and just `truncate` the `#temp` table, do you observe any `logical_reads`?

Answer (score 2):

The data in there is not really dropped, first of all. It has to do with how Temdb is implemented

Also, Microsoft has a great blog on TempDB and contention that addresses the following points:

[Tempdb - Files, Trace flags, updates - Microsoft Blogs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/tempdb-files-and-trace-flags-and-updates-oh-my/)

> We are continuing to work on improving tempdb performance and metadata
>   contention, but in the meantime, there are some best practices you can
>   employ in your code that might help avoid the contention:
>
> 1. Do not explicitly drop temp tables at the end of a stored procedure, they will get cleaned up when the session that created them
>      ends.
> 2. Do not alter temp tables after they have been created.
> 3. **Do not truncate temp tables**
> 4. Move index creation statements on temp tables to the new inline index creation syntax that was introduced in SQL Server 2014.